# Cannot stop docker-compose logs -f with CTRL + C any more

Tags: shell, terminal, docker, signals, docker-compose

`docker-compose logs -f` is a useful command to view the logs of containers in the background and follow them to see new entries immediately. It seems that with the latest stable V2.1.0 it's not possible to quit those foreground process with <kbd>control-c</kbd> any more:

```
$ docker-compose logs -f
...
webserver-1  | [Sat Nov 13 12:10:33.814463 2021] [core:notice] [pid 1] AH00094: Command line: 'apache2 -D FOREGROUND'
^C^C^C
```

It only prints `^C` without terminating the process. Even when pressing it multiple times, which usually kills the process immediately, nothing happens. The only thing which works is [<kbd>control-\</kbd>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8221984/3276634), which prints a huge stacktrace:

```
^C^C^C^\SIGQUIT: quit
PC=0x7b950 m=0 sigcode=128

goroutine 0 [idle]:
runtime.futex(0x1491b10, 0x80, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x56a08, 0x18473b0, 0x1a9d8, 0x4c394, ...)
    runtime/sys_linux_arm.s:443 +0x1c
runtime.futexsleep(0x1491b10, 0x0, 0xffffffff, 0xffffffff)
    runtime/os_linux.go:44 +0x184
runtime.notesleep(0x1491b10)
    runtime/lock_futex.go:159 +0xac
runtime.mPark()
    runtime/proc.go:1340 +0x20
runtime.stopm()
    runtime/proc.go:2301 +0x78
runtime.findrunnable(0x1846000, 0x0)
    runtime/proc.go:2960 +0x84c
runtime.schedule()
    runtime/proc.go:3169 +0x2bc
runtime.park_m(0x18821c0)
    runtime/proc.go:3318 +0x80
runtime.mcall(0x78b1c)
    runtime/asm_arm.s:285 +0x5c

goroutine 1 [semacquire, 5 minutes]:
sync.runtime_Semacquire(0x187aea4)
    runtime/sema.go:56 +0x34
sync.(*WaitGroup).Wait(0x187aea4)
    sync/waitgroup.go:130 +0x84
golang.org/x/sync/errgroup.(*Group).Wait(0x187aea0, 0x1b27380, 0x1bbe440)
    golang.org/x/sync@v0.0.0-20210220032951-036812b2e83c/errgroup/errgroup.go:40 +0x24
github.com/docker/compose/v2/pkg/compose.(*composeService).Logs(0x1ae6370, 0xe3c114, 0x180af60, 0x18a0a20, 0x11, 0xe37fc8, 0x187ac60, 0x189d798, 0x0, 0x1, ...)
    github.com/docker/compose/v2/pkg/compose/logs.go:56 +0x214
github.com/docker/compose/v2/pkg/api.(*ServiceProxy).Logs(0x19081c0, 0xe3c114, 0x180af60, 0x18a0a20, 0x11, 0xe37fc8, 0x187ac60, 0x189d798, 0x0, 0x1, ...)
    github.com/docker/compose/v2/pkg/api/proxy.go:200 +0x6c
github.com/docker/compose/v2/cmd/compose.runLogs(0xe3c114, 0x180af60, 0xe45a9c, 0x19081c0, 0x19bb540, 0x0, 0x1, 0xca45ce, 0x3, 0x0, ...)
    github.com/docker/compose/v2/cmd/compose/logs.go:71 +0x180
github.com/docker/compose/v2/cmd/compose.logsCommand.func1(0xe3c114, 0x180af60, 0x189d798, 0x0, 0x1, 0x18000e0, 0xa92b3c)
    github.com/docker/compose/v2/cmd/compose/logs.go:50 +0x6c
github.com/docker/compose/v2/cmd/compose.Adapt.func1(0xe3c114, 0x180af60, 0x1927ce0, 0x189d798, 0x0, 0x1, 0x12, 0x588734)
    github.com/docker/compose/v2/cmd/compose/compose.go:85 +0x44
github.com/docker/compose/v2/cmd/compose.AdaptCmd.func1(0x1927ce0, 0x189d798, 0x0, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0)
    github.com/docker/compose/v2/cmd/compose/compose.go:64 +0x104
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute(0x1927ce0, 0x189f720, 0x1, 0x1, 0x1927ce0, 0x189f720)
    github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.2.1/command.go:856 +0x354
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC(0x1c79b80, 0x1c79b80, 0x189f710, 0x3)
    github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.2.1/command.go:974 +0x280
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute(...)
    github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.2.1/command.go:902
github.com/docker/cli/cli-plugins/plugin.RunPlugin(0x19080e0, 0x19271e0, 0xca53b9, 0x5, 0xcaca17, 0xb, 0xe1bba4, 0x6, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
    github.com/docker/cli@v20.10.7+incompatible/cli-plugins/plugin/plugin.go:51 +0xe8
github.com/docker/cli/cli-plugins/plugin.Run(0xd1f2d8, 0xca53b9, 0x5, 0xcaca17, 0xb, 0xe1bba4, 0x6, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
    github.com/docker/cli@v20.10.7+incompatible/cli-plugins/plugin/plugin.go:64 +0xdc
main.pluginMain()
    github.com/docker/compose/v2/cmd/main.go:41 +0x6c
main.main()
    github.com/docker/compose/v2/cmd/main.go:74 +0x138

goroutine 33 [chan send, 5 minutes]:
github.com/docker/compose/v2/cmd/formatter.init.0.func1(0x1b199e0)
    github.com/docker/compose/v2/cmd/formatter/colors.go:120 +0x224
created by github.com/docker/compose/v2/cmd/formatter.init.0
    github.com/docker/compose/v2/cmd/formatter/colors.go:104 +0x1fc

goroutine 8 [chan receive]:
k8s.io/klog/v2.(*loggingT).flushDaemon(0x14914f0)
    k8s.io/klog/v2@v2.8.0/klog.go:1164 +0x70
created by k8s.io/klog/v2.init.0
    k8s.io/klog/v2@v2.8.0/klog.go:418 +0x100

goroutine 36 [syscall, 5 minutes]:
os/signal.signal_recv(0xe35dd8)
    runtime/sigqueue.go:168 +0x158
os/signal.loop()
    os/signal/signal_unix.go:23 +0x14
created by os/signal.Notify.func1.1
    os/signal/signal.go:151 +0x34

goroutine 15 [chan receive, 5 minutes]:
github.com/docker/compose/v2/pkg/compose.(*printer).Run(0x1bc60a0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    github.com/docker/compose/v2/pkg/compose/printer.go:66 +0x94
github.com/docker/compose/v2/pkg/compose.(*composeService).Logs.func2(0x0, 0x0)
    github.com/docker/compose/v2/pkg/compose/logs.go:45 +0x44
golang.org/x/sync/errgroup.(*Group).Go.func1(0x187aea0, 0x1bc60b0)
    golang.org/x/sync@v0.0.0-20210220032951-036812b2e83c/errgroup/errgroup.go:57 +0x50
created by golang.org/x/sync/errgroup.(*Group).Go
    golang.org/x/sync@v0.0.0-20210220032951-036812b2e83c/errgroup/errgroup.go:54 +0x50

trap    0x0
error   0x0
oldmask 0x0
r0      0x1491b10
r1      0x80
r2      0x0
r3      0x0
r4      0x0
r5      0x0
r6      0x0
r7      0xf0
r8      0x7
r9      0x1
r10     0x1491588
fp      0x7
ip      0x1491758
sp      0xbed1843c
lr      0x42fac
pc      0x7b950
cpsr    0xa0000010
fault   0x0
```

On an older test machine with V1.21.0 it works well using <kbd>control-c</kbd>:

```
$ docker-compose logs -f 
nextcloud_redis    | 1:M 26 Sep 2021 19:58:26.051 * 100 changes in 300 seconds. Saving...
^CERROR: Aborting.
```

Any idea why <kbd>control-c</kbd> does nothing in the V2.1.0 docker-compose release? It's the first CLI application I see, where this doesn't work. I never even know <kbd>control-\</kbd> before. It seems not a good alternative to me, since it will mess up the terminal with a lot of log entries from go, as shown above.

I have tested this on another Linux machine and even on Windows with MobaXterm, so it seems not an issue of my client. My main client is Manjaro 21.1.6 and Docker-Compose runs on a Raspberry Pi 4 with Raspbian 10 Buster if this is important.

Comment: Here's the github issue: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/8880.  It looks like the maintainers are aware of the issue.

Comment: Wow only 4 users in this world with this problem?

Comment: @wutzebaer Or nobody is looking in the logs? :D I was also wondering about this

Comment: i downgraded to v2.0.1 now it is working

Answer (score 1):

It was a known bug. This is now [fixed](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/8977) in Docker Compose 2.2.2